# reliably monitor/track/log user file accesses on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, filesystems, hook, dll-injection

I need to track all files accessed (created, opened, read) by a user and log these actions for further processing within a separate application. I have investigated and searched for possible ways to achieve this (as simple as possible) and came up with the following solutions:

1. Hook kernel32.dll and intercept all
   file specific functions like
   CreateFileA, OpenFile,etc. I thought
   of modifying the IAT and provide
   wrapper functions. I'd still forward
   the calls to the original functions,
   but report which files where
   accessed when to my application.
   This sounds easy to achieve, but I
   doubt it will work flawlessly on
   Windows 7 as it appears to me new
   security restrictions prevent
   successful hooking by modifying the
   import address table. Maybe somebody
   knows better :)
2. Write a file system minifilter and
   make the callback functions report
   about file accesses. As I haven't
   written a minifilter before I don't
   know if this is a feasible
   approach. I believe development of a
   minifilter requires far more effort.
   Maybe somebody can point out some
   resources like tutorials on writing
   simple filesystem minifilters.

I know of Microsoft's Detour library but at this stage I would like to avoid to use it, as the hook in general is quite simple. Is there any reliable way of hooking file functions in Windows 7 at all without using Detours or EasyHook?
Concerning minifilters: I believe what I want to achieve is quite simple compared to for example filters, which deal with encryption. However I have no experience in writing minifilters and cannot estimate how much effort it takes to achieve my goals. All examples I stumbled upon have dealt with file system filters and not minifilters.

I'm thankful for any hints and suggestions :)

Greetings,
curiosity

Comment: My money is on the file system (mini)filter driver (You can check out */src/filesystem/miniFilter/scanner* sample in the [WinDDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdk/).)

Comment: Using a minifilter, can I track back which program issued the access initially?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: That's not in the realm of reliable, or not in the realm of scalable

Comment: Good suggestion. This would require to watch all volumes including dealing with arriving and leaving volumes. Do you have a clue how this approach scales when watching a whole volume?

Comment: With FileSystemWatcher class you can monitor create/update/delete/rename operations only, we cant use this class to track file access.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product, which provides a ready-to-use filter driver and lets you write all logic in user mode?

Comment: Hello Eugene. I have checked your CallbackFilter. It appears to be a solid product. However, I cannot afford to license it at the moment. Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: @curiosity we offer *significant* discounts and installment plans, if you are interested. For private non-commercial projects this might be not an option, I understand. Also for scientific and educational purposes (such as graduation project or short-term needs) we offer free time-limited licenses (for 6 to 12 months).

Comment: @curiosity BTW we offer free licenses as well now.